# Error While running the SSIS Package through Control-M

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, control-m

I have 1 SSIS package with simple Data flow task to read the data from CSV file and load it into the SQL server.
We have 3 servers : 
1 unix server for control-M (RedHat Server7.6)
1 windows server for SQL database and SSIS 
1 Window server for storing the files.

When we run the package from Control-M then it is not able to read the files from file server, but when we run the package from SQL Agent in SSIS then it is executing successfully.

I have already given the permission of file server folder to the account that we are using in Control-M connection profile. PFB Error for reference.

> Data Flow Task:Error: Cannot open the datafile "Location".
>
> Data Flow Task:Error: Flat File Source failed the pre-execute phase
>   and returned error code 0xC020200E.

Comment: Does it work if you do not involve CTRL-M in the process? What user is it trying to open the file under?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run SSIS packages in Control-M an Agent must exist on the server that contains the SSIS package.  D

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Control-M for Databases installed on the Agent? That is often a better way to run SSIS.